# Symfony form, One-to-one relationship, one side can be null

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony-forms, one-to-one, symfony-3.2

I have a `MainConfig` entity that has One-to-one relationship with `LedConfig` entity. `LedConfig` can be null.

```
<?php

namespace ...


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class MainConfig
{

    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="...\LedConfig", cascade={"all"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="led_config_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=true, unique = true)
     */
    private $ledConfig = null;

    ...

}

<?php

namespace ...


use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
...

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class LedConfig
{

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;


    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float")
     */
    private $lowerVoltageThreshold = 11.9;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="float")
     * @Assert\Type(type="float")
     */
    private $upperVoltageThreshold = 12.85;


}

<?php

namespace ...;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
...

class MainConfigType extends AbstractType
{
    ...

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add(...)
            ->add('ledConfig', LedConfigType::class)
            ...
    }
    ...
}
```

I am inserting a main config into a database automatically without using Symfony forms. So, if I set led config to null in the code - field `led_config_id` inside main config table is correctly set to NULL.

But, when I am updating the main config, I am using HTTP PUT request that is processed through Symfony forms.
I am using JSON, so request body looks like this:

```
{..., "ssid":"test","runningMode":"force_on","led_config":null, ...}
```

After the form is processed, property `$ledConfig` inside MainConfig entity is magically instantiated as `LedConfig` object with **all properties set to NULL**?!
And database update fails because it tries to save LedEnttiy with empty fields.
Why does it happen?

Can someone please help me and indicate what I did wrong?

EDIT:
I could hack it in the controller update action, after the form validation:

```
/**
 * @Route("...")
 * @Method("PUT")
 */
public function updateMainConfigAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $requestData = \GuzzleHttp\json_decode($request->getContent(), true);

    ...

    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        throw $this->throwApiProblemValidationException($form);
    }

    if (empty($requestData['led_config'])) {
        $mainConfig->setLedConfig(null);
    }

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $em->persist($mainConfig);
    $em->flush();

    ...

}
```

but that is kind of dirty...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are the `empty_data` and the `required` options on Symfony's FormType.

The `empty_data` option has following behaviour:

1. when data_class is set and `required` option is `true`, then `empty_data` is new $data_class();
2. when data_class is set and `required` option is `false`, then `empty_data` is null;
3. when data_class is not set and `compound` option is `true`, then `empty_data` is empty array;
4. when data_class is not set and `compound` option is `false`, then `empty_data` is empty string.

The `required` option is `true` by default and the data_class is set on the ledConfig field, so when you left it empty, then new class is set to it. If you want the ledConfig field to be explicitly set to `null` when no value is selected, you can set directly the `empty_data` option.

In your case, you want the #2 scenario, so set `required` option to `false` and `empty_data` option set to `null` on ledConfig field:

```
...
$builder
    ->add(...)
    ->add('ledConfig', LedConfigType::class, array(
        'required' => false
        'empty_data' => null
    ))
    ...
```

Comment: Hm... I already tried with `...array('required' => false)`, but no help.

Comment: Even though, in a theory, it should work XD
I must more carefully investigate code.

Comment: And did you tried to set the `empty_data` option to `null` on ledConfig field?

Comment: It works if I set `->add('ledConfig', LedConfigType::class, array('required' => false, 'empty_data' => null))`.
I'll accept your answer, but please update code, so if anybody else would have the same problem, they don't need to read comments to find out correct solution :)
Tnx!